# How can I tell the accuracy of coordinates conversion by cs2cs?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, cs2cs

For example, when I try this:

```
cs2cs +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +to +proj=tmerc +lat_
0=22.31213333333334 +lon_0=114.1785555555556 +k=1 +x_0=836694.05 +y_0=819069.8 +
ellps=intl +towgs84=-162.619,-276.959,-161.764,0.067753,-2.24365,-1.15883,-1.094
25 +units=m +no_defs
```

When I put

> 114.1689 22.4518

It outputs

> 835447.18       834705.40 3.11

Can I tell from the result, the accuracy and possible numeric error of the result? Some meters or some percent?

Comment: I don't think so. That post is about the accuracy of coordinates. I am talking about the accuracy of conversion.

Comment: In your case, four decimal places for your lat/long coordinates corresponds with 10 m precision. So I would not care about potential numeric errors.